# Starting a batch file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

i have created a batch file(suppose batch1) which is in a folder(suppose folder A) and is programmed to start another batch(suppose batch2) which is in another directory(suppose folder B). Batch2 is programmed to extract a file(suppose xyz.tar which is both in folder A and B). But when i start batch1 it starts batch2 but batch2 extracts the file in folder A not in B. The examples below can help you to understand.
Here are my batch files.

::batch1

```
ECHO This is batch1  
"D:\folder B\batch2.bat"
```

::batch2

```
ECHO This is batch2  
7z.exe x xyz.tar >nul
```

Folder A contains batch1.bat and xyz.tar.

Folder B contains batch2.bat and xyz.tar.

batch2 starts but it starts extracting the file which is in folder A but it should extract the xyz.tar in the folder B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of your batch2.bat, after your `@echo off/setlocal` try

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
```

Comment: Small edits.  Remove the trailing % sign and enclose %~dp0 in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must change the working folder to extract at the correct position.

try something like:

```
cd "d:\folder B"
 batch2.bat
```